# Retrieve data based on conditions in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, select

I am having a table in MySQL called `hash` and it has 2 fields, **primary_key** and **hashValue**. I entered data into them using the following code:

```
insert into hash values (1,'car dog play ball morning dark night')
insert into hash values (2,'car dog play ball people morning dark night sydney love')
```

Now, I need to do the following.

1. enter a list of words.
2. enter a percentage value.
3. compare words inputted with each row and get the percentage of those words available in rows.
4. get the data rows which is above the percentage value.

Ex:

Imagine I enter the following word set: `sydney love people track`

Imagine I enter the percentage as: `20`

Now, the row with primary_key = 2 contains 10 words, and 3 of them (sydney love people) are in the inputted word list. That 3 words means 30% (3 words out of 10) in the second row. Since the inputted percentage is 20 and 30 is above that, I need to retrieve that row. Just like this, if there are any other rows above 20, I need to get them too.

How can do this kind of thing in MySQL? Please note my database knowledge is below average (I know insert,delete,update and JDBC in Java).

I did this using Java before. I read a file line by line and did the same. It is taking too much time. Now I am going to replace the file with a DB but I can't apply the same method to here, because the original DB will be really big and reading every line via Java will be a mess. FYI there will be millions of records.

Comment: You are 100% sure that you need to do it in database? Because it would be trivial to do in the programming language.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: Yes. I did this using Java before. I read a file and did the same. It is taking too much time. And, I can't apply the same method to here, because the original DB will be really big and reading every line will be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I would change DB structure introducing many-to-many relations hash<->word

Just create 3 tables `hash`, `words`, `hash_words`. Each your has could be stored in the 3 tables.

It's much easier to work with the `hash_words` table. All your calculations would be just results of aggregate functions using on SQL level. (`SUM/COUNT/AVG`)

Comment: Hi. what does `hash` table contains, what does `words` table contains and what does `hash_words` contains? anyway, as I mentioned before, the 'user' is the one going to insert that list of words and percentage. Table contains the pre-inserted words so we can compare.

Comment: **words** has id, word fields. **hash** has in fact id only. **hash_words** has pair of ids hash_id and word_id

Comment: I am sorry I am not clear. can you please explain? can you please be kind enough to show the db structure? maybe create those and show the structure if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the datastructure I would advice something like this:

```
INSERT INTO hash([key],[word])
VALUES
(1,'car'),
(1,'dog'),
(1,'play'),
(1,'morning'),
(1,'night'),
(2,'car'),
(2,'dog'),
(2,'play'),
(2,'ball'),
(2,'people'),
(2,'morning'),
(2,'dark'),
(2,'night'),
(2,'sydney'),
(2,'love')
```

Then you can do a query like this:

```
select key,FullCount,SubCount,(100.0/FullCount)*SubCount as 'Percent' from (
select * from (select key,COUNT(*) FullCount from hash group by key) a
left join 
(select key as subkey,COUNT(*) SubCount from hash where word in ('sydney','love','people','track') group by key) b
on a.key=b.subkey) c where (100.0/FullCount)*SubCount>20
```

(Note: not tested on MySQL!)

Add some Indexes and you are done.

Comment: which means? in your case, I have to remove the primary key right? What is the structure you are suggesting?

Comment: Just remove the primary key. The key field must not be unique in this case.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But in real scenario, as I mentioned above, there will be lot of data. That means, in this manner, "billions" of records. so, will this work?

Comment: Billions? In terms of 10^9??? I think the answer to "will this work" depends on the hardware that you can use. Big MySQL Cluster? Perhaps! Your Laptop? No!

Comment: No. We are using a seperate server